# Can't delete file after being renamed (file is opened)

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, delete-file

I am using **icefaces** to upload files to relative path in my web app `(mywebapp/audio)`, then after the file is getting uploaded I rename it to save its extension as follows:

```
public static File changeExtToWav(FileInfo fileInfo,
            StringBuffer originalFileName) {
        log.debug("changeExtToWav");
        int mid = fileInfo.getFile().getName().lastIndexOf(".");
        String fileName = fileInfo.getFile().getName().substring(0, mid);
        originalFileName.append(fileName);
        log.debug("originalFileName: " + originalFileName);
        String newFileName = fileName + "_" + new Date().getTime() + "."
                + "wav";
        File newFile = new File(fileInfo.getFile().getParent() + "/"
                + newFileName);
        log.debug("newFileName: " + newFile.getName());
        fileInfo.getFile().renameTo(newFile);
        return newFile;
    }
```

after the file is getting uploaded, sometimes I want to delete it from UI button as follows:

```
try {

            File fileToDelete = new File(filePath); // correct file path
            log.debug("file exists: " + fileToDelete.exists()); // true
            fileToDelete.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the file path is correct, and I get no exceptions, but the file is not deleted (I am using java 6 btw).
please advise how to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:** using the following useful method, I can get that the **file is opened**, any ideas how to close it ?

```
public String getReasonForFileDeletionFailureInPlainEnglish(File file) {
    try {
        if (!file.exists())
            return "It doesn't exist in the first place.";
        else if (file.isDirectory() && file.list().length > 0)
            return "It's a directory and it's not empty.";
        else
            return "Somebody else has it open, we don't have write permissions, or somebody stole my disk.";
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return "We're sandboxed and don't have filesystem access.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `fileToDelete.delete();` return?

Comment: @GETah, it returns false because the file is not deleted.

Comment: did you release all resources associated with the file you're trying to delete?

Comment: @user1329572, how to do that ?

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1729049/1140748, it can help you know the reason of the deletion fail.

Comment: @alain.janinm, thanks for the useful link, from it i can get that the file is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the file is open, then there is two solutions :

- You have a stream in your program open on this file. Note that afaik it's a problem on Windows, with Unix I can delete a File even if a stream is opened on it.
- You have an other process using this file. So in this case you can't do anything from Java.

In the log it tells also that it can be a permission problem, are you sure you have enough privileges?

You can also use [Files#delete(Path path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29) (jdk7) to have more details about the issue.