# Deleting an existing file using f.delete() method

Tags: java, file

```
String book_name = book_list.getModel().getElementAt(book_list.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
System.out.println("File name : "+book_name);

File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Surya\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\New_Doodle\\Library\\"+book_name);
System.out.println("Path:"+f.getAbsolutePath());

if(f.exists())
    System.out.println("Book Exists");
else
    System.out.println("Not Exixts");

if(f.isFile())
{
    System.out.println("It is File");
}
else
    System.out.println("It is Directory");

System.out.println(f.isAbsolute());
          
if (f.delete())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Deleted");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operation Failed");
}
```

### Output

```
File name : `Twilight03-Eclipse.pdf`  
Path: `C:\Users\Surya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\New_Doodle\Library\Twilight03-Eclipse.pdf`  
Book Exists  
It is File  
true  
Operation Failed (dialog box)  
File is not deleted
```

Comment: Does it show the "Book Deleted" dialog?

Comment: more importantly.. do you read twilight??

Comment: Do you get any exception? your output looks like you don't xome into your last  if-else. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Is the file still open in another program?

Comment: The file may be in use by other programme.

Comment: @assylias - No, it is giving "operation failed" dialog

Comment: @Aniket - No I didn't open it

Comment: If i use "Files.delete(path)" method, then it is showing that it is being used by another process...

Comment: @Surya than you can't delete the file if it's in use.

Comment: Importantly, the code is working fine for other drive files, but not for Local Disk(C:\\)... I also gave full control in the file security properties....

Comment: @Arpit, I know that... But i dont know which process is using it... because i didn't any operations on the file... First operation is delete only...

Comment: @Surya check the task manager.

Comment: @Surya Can you delete the file manually (from a file explorer)?

Comment: Yeah, I can delete it manually from task manager...

Comment: sorry, from file manager...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package to find out why your delete operation fails. It gives you a detailed reason for the same.

Answer (score 1):

A deletion may fail due to one or more reasons:

- File does not exist (use File#exists() to test).
- File is locked
  (because it is opened by another app (or your own code!).
- You are not
  authorized (but that would have thrown a SecurityException, not
  returned false!).

This function could help:

```
public String getReasonForFileDeletionFailureInPlainEnglish(File file) {
    try {
        if (!file.exists())
            return "It doesn't exist in the first place.";
        else if (file.isDirectory() && file.list().length > 0)
            return "It's a directory and it's not empty.";
        else
            return "Somebody else has it open, we don't have write permissions, or somebody stole my disk.";
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return "We're sandboxed and don't have filesystem access.";
    }
}
```

[How to tell why a file deletion fails in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729049/how-to-tell-why-a-file-deletion-fails-in-java)

Comment: I have seen the same answer by CoryPetosky

Comment: `File exist` and `isFile` is checked in OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try{
             File file = new File("C:/ProgramData/Logs/" + selectedJLItem);

             if(file.delete()){
                 System.out.println(file.getName() + " Was deleted!");
             }else{
                 System.out.println("Delete Operation Failed. Check: " + file);
             }
         }catch(Exception e1){
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```