# Pdf not deleting when i'm using delete method

Tags: java

I try to delete a PDF File but its not working. when I try to delete a simple text is working  test.txt . Is there any other problem?

*Source Code:*

```
try{
        File f1=new File("D:\\test.pdf");       
        if(f1.delete()){
            System.out.println(f1.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the file is open...? Also check the task manager.

Comment: this will surely help your debugging:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729049/how-to-tell-why-a-file-deletion-fails-in-java

Comment: Are you sure this is the only piece of code where you are operating on this file or do you have more code, which is not shared?

Comment: as @Sebastian says the file was open :( thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading/writing from file in the program?
If you are reading/writing using stream and don't close the stream then also it will not get deleted.

Comment: No,file is just open before the application is run

Comment: If the file is open then the application will not be able to delete it. It would be good if you share the complete code of this file processing. That will help us identify the root cause.

Answer (score -1):

The file may be in use by other application(s). Also you can use `deleteOnExit()` in place of `delete()`

Comment: @ZouZou I didn't had the privileges (enough points) to add a comment to the question at that time. Otherwise, I would have done that

Comment: @Mubin You need at least 50 rep to comment. 57-10+2*2 = 51. So you had the privileges to comment. Anyway, that's not so important.

Comment: When I answered this question, I had 41 points. Received 10 points later for upvotes.