# How to read/write a file in Java

Tags: java, io, file-handling

I would like to replace some items in a file, based on some regular expressions. In order to do that:

- I read the file line per line
- For every line, I check for the regular expression and I perform the replacement
- Every line gets written in an array of strings

When all this is finished, I try to delete the file (in order to recreate it again with the replaced lines).

For some reason this does not work: it seems that Java keeps a handle on that file, even after the BufferedReader has been closed.

Does anybody have a solution for this (newbie) question?

Code excerpt:

```
      Pattern oDatePattern   = Pattern.compile("at \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} "); // meaning: "at xx:xx:xx"
      Pattern oTimePattern   = Pattern.compile("Kernel time [0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+ User time: [0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"); // "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+" stands for any floating point number
      Pattern oMemoryPattern = Pattern.compile("\\([0-9,A-F]*\\)"); // "[0-9,A-F]*" stands for any hexadecimal number 
      Matcher oDateMatcher;
      Matcher oTimeMatcher;
      Matcher oMemoryMatcher;

      List<String> sLog_Content = new ArrayList<String>();

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sLp_LogFile));
      try {
        String sLine = br.readLine();

        while (sLine != null) {
          System.out.println("ORIG : " + sLine);
          oDateMatcher = oDatePattern.matcher(sLine);
          sLine        = oDateMatcher.replaceAll("at <timestamp> ");
          oTimeMatcher = oTimePattern.matcher(sLine);
          sLine        = oTimeMatcher.replaceAll("Kernel time <Kernel_Time_usage> User time: <User_Time_usage>");
          oMemoryMatcher = oMemoryPattern.matcher(sLine);
          sLine          = oMemoryMatcher.replaceAll("<Memory_Address>");
          System.out.println("REPL : " + sLine);
          sLog_Content.add(sLine);
          sLine = br.readLine();
        }
      } finally {
        br.close();
      }

      System.out.println("All lines are read and regex replaced, try to delete the file");

      File tst_File = new File(sLp_LogFile);
      if (tst_File.exists()) {
        System.out.println(sLp_LogFile + " exists");
      } else {
        System.out.println(sLp_LogFile + " does not exist");
      }

      if (tst_File.delete()) {
        System.out.println(sLp_LogFile + " is deleted");
      } else {
        System.out.println(sLp_LogFile + " is not deleted");
      }
```

Output logs:

```
ORIG : Reading buffer 1 (0000000002ED0070) at 15:40:44 (index 125999, size 4410000 lines 126000, total lines read 126000)
REPL : Reading buffer 1 <Memory_Address> at <timestamp> (index 125999, size 4410000 lines 126000, total lines read 126000)
...
ORIG : Sending buffer 1 (0000000002ED0070) at 15:40:44 (index 125999, size 4410000, lines 126000, total lines sent 126000)
REPL : Sending buffer 1 <Memory_Address> at <timestamp> (index 125999, size 4410000, lines 126000, total lines sent 126000)
...
ORIG : Kernel time 0.2808 User time: 0.312
REPL : Kernel time <Kernel_Time_usage> User time: <User_Time_usage>
...
All lines are read and regex replaced, try to delete the file
D:\Logfile_lp.log exists
D:\Logfile_lp.log is not deleted
```

Comment: I have the following suggestion: preserve FileReader reference and close it as well.  If you use Java 7 or later,  you can use TRY-with-resources syntax.

Comment: @brso05 - Unnecessary.  The `close()` call on the `BufferedReader` will call `close()` on the `FileReader`.

Comment: can you try `Files.delete(path)`? (needs java7+)

Comment: Just as a test, I have preserved FileReader and closed that one, but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: I have tried to use "Files", but it seems not to work (Files is not found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,
I would like to thank you all for having searched for a solution of this problem. Unfortunately the problem is not Java based: the file I'm trying to write to is created by a redirection `cmd /c <program>.exe >> <output>.log`, and it seems that Windows has not fully flushed the output buffer towards the output file, creating the problem.

I am currently using following (very dirty) work-around for this issue:

```
boolean bFile_can_be_opened = false;
while (!bFile_can_be_opened) {
  try {
    fwLog2 = new FileWriter(sLp_LogFile, true);
    bFile_can_be_opened = true;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {}
}
```

Further information on this issue can be found under the following new StackOverflow question: [How to release a file, locked by the application, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770754/how-to-release-a-file-locked-by-the-application-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation is that your application has the file open somewhere else.

Or it could be another application that has the file open.

Or maybe the application / user has permission to read the file but not to delete it.

---

I concur with the suggestion of using `Files.delete` ..

Comment: In fact, this file has been created using following piece of code: `exitcode = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline).waitFor();`. I assume that the `waitFor()` method waits for the entire process to be finished, which means that the according file has been written completely and its handle has been released.

Answer (score 2):

I see no issues in your code.

Seemingly closing the `BufferReader` ensure the file is closed. (cf [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388602/do-i-need-to-close-both-filereader-and-bufferedreader)).

Maybe you can give a try to [`Files.delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html) cf [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729049/how-to-tell-why-a-file-deletion-fails-in-java).
It will give more information about the deletion fail by throwing different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, I do not know as much things as you. But if I am right you should save your changes first a temp file. Afterwards you will read again the temp file and later you'll write to your real file. I hope my comment will help you.